# how to merge 2 boolean dataframes with different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

How to merge df1 and df2 into df?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['4.txt', '5.txt', '6.txt'], [1,0,0], [1,1,1])),
             columns = ['file', 'is_about_heroes', 'is_about_pony'])


df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['5.txt', '6.txt'], [1,0], [1,0])),
         columns = ['file', 'is_about_pony', 'is_about_wolf'])
```

---

```
df1 

    file  is_about_heroes  is_about_pony
0  4.txt                1              1
1  5.txt                0              1
2  6.txt                0              1

df2    
    file  is_about_pony  is_about_wolf
0  5.txt              1              1
1  6.txt              0              0
```

And I want to get df which is the boolean union of two previous dfs.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['4.txt', '5.txt', '6.txt'], [1,0,0], [1,1,1], [0,1,0])),
                 columns = ['file', 'is_about_heroes', 'is_about_pony', 'is_about_wolf'])

    file  is_about_heroes  is_about_pony  is_about_wolf
0  4.txt                1              1              0
1  5.txt                0              1              1
2  6.txt                0              1              0
```

Is it possible without several manual cycles?

Comment: You have a conflict between `df1` and `df2` for the file `6.txt` in `is_about_pony`

Comment: @James it is not a conflict. There is boolean meaning. Consider some algorithm gives me df1 and another gives df2. I want to use logical OR for df1 and df2. For 6.txt then I have True OR  False, it should be True in the resulting df. The problem is: how to manipulate with dataframes if values are boolean. How to perform logicals operations? In my special case dataframes has different shapes. How to deal in that special way.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `merge`:

```
In [186]: df1.merge(df2, how='left').fillna(0)
Out[186]:
    file  is_about_heroes  is_about_pony  is_about_wolf
0  4.txt                1              1            0.0
1  5.txt                0              1            1.0
2  6.txt                0              1            0.0
```

Comment: How to prevent types changes?